# Using PolyLines to connect drag and drop shapes with FabricJS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'd like to use a polyline to connect two rectangles and stay connected to the same points on the respective rectangles as the rectangles move (specifically, for two rectangles on a page, I'd like the polyline to connect the bottom middle point of one rectangle to the top middle part of another rectangle. The reason I'm using a PolyLine is because I will eventually be adding in elbows down the road as well). I'm having issues with the polyline coordinates updating in response to the moving rectangles though.

This demonstrates some of the issues I am hitting:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
rect = null;
line = null;

function addLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  var coords = [{x: x1, y: y1}, {x: x2, y: y2}];
    
  this.line = new fabric.Polyline(coords, {
    stroke: 'green',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    selectable: true,
    evented: false
  });

  this.canvas.add(this.line);
}

function addRect(left, top, width, height, line1, line2, line3, line4) {
  this.rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: left,
    top: top,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    fill: '#9f9',
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    centeredRotation: true 
  });

  this.rect.line1 = line1;
  this.rect.line2 = line2;
  this.rect.line3 = line3;
  this.rect.line4 = line4;

  this.canvas.add(this.rect);
}

var r1_left = 10;
var r1_top = 20;
var r1_width = 125;
var r1_height = 150;
var r2_left = 350;
var r2_top = 300;
var r2_width = 125;
var r2_height = 150;

addLine(r1_left + r1_width/2, r1_top + r1_height, r2_left + r2_width/2, r2_top);
addRect(r1_left, r1_top, r1_width, r1_height, null, null, this.line, null);  
addRect(r2_left, r2_top, r2_width, r2_height, this.line, null, null, null);

this.canvas.renderAll();

this.canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
  var p = e.target;

  if (p.line1) {
    let x_2_new = p.left + p.width/2; 
    let y_2_new = p.top;
    p.line1.set('points', [p.line1.points[0], {'x': x_2_new, 'y': y_2_new}]);
    p.line1.set('height', y_2_new - p.line1.points[0]['y']);
    p.line1.set('width', x_2_new - p.line1.points[0]['x']);
    p.set('oCoords', p.line1.calcCoords());
  } else if (p.line2) {
    p.line2.set({'points': [{'x': p.left + p.width, 'y': p.top + p.height/2}, p.line2.points[1]]});
  } else if (p.line3) {
    p.line3.set({'points': [{'x': p.left + p.width/2, 'y': p.top + p.height}, p.line3.points[1]]});
  } else if (p.line4) {
    p.line4.set({'points': [p.line4.points[0], {'x': p.left, 'y': p.top + p.height/2}]});
  } 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="c" width="700" height="700" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
    <script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For the upper rectangle, I have tried simply setting the x and y coordinates as the object moves. With this, I encounter the error that x and y seem to be bound by the oCoords and aCoords of the line.

For the lower rectangle, I have tried setting the coordinates directly. With this, the entire line seems to shift around the page.

Any advice about what I could change here would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code, what you need, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhxru3d0)

```js
(function() {
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
  fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

  function makeCircle(left, top, line1, line2) {
    var c = new fabric.Rect({
      top: top,
      left: left,
      width: 30,
      height: 30,
      selection: false,
      fill: '#ccc'
      });
      c.hasControls = c.hasBorders = false;

      c.line1 = line1;
      c.line2 = line2;

      return c;
  }

  function makeLine(coords) {
    return new fabric.Line(coords, {
      fill: 'red',
      stroke: 'red',
      strokeWidth: 5,
      selectable: false,
      evented: false,
    });
  }

  var line = makeLine([ 250, 125, 250, 375 ]),
      line2 = makeLine([ 250, 375, 250, 350 ]);

  canvas.add(line);

  canvas.add(
    makeCircle(line.get('x1'), line.get('y1'), null, line),
    makeCircle(line.get('x2'), line.get('y2'), line, line2),
  );

  canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
    var p = e.target;
    p.line1 && p.line1.set({ 'x2': p.left, 'y2': p.top });
    p.line2 && p.line2.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top });
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
})();
```

```html
<div>
    <canvas id="c" width="700" height="575" style="border:1px solid #999"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.7.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually, my use case is different - I'm looking specifically at PolyLines and not at Lines. Though I did adapt my code from the FabricJS Demo (http://fabricjs.com/stickman), PolyLines assign coordinates differently.

Comment: @Mikmac Did you get it working with PolyLines?